# MVC 4 - issue with routing to non-area controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a project that I am upgrading from MVC 2 -> MVC 4.  During the transition from MVC 2 -> MVC 3, I noticed that some of my hyperlinks broke and were no longer matching the routes as defined before.  I have the following project structure:

```
...
App_Data
Areas
  Test
    Controllers
        TestController
    Views
    Models
Controllers
    PartialController
Views
Scripts
...
```

The links that are generated are in the format `/Test/Partial/Render`.  If I go back and run the project before the migration, the `PartialController` `Render` action is hit as expected.  However, now the app says that it can't find an action because there is no `Test/Partial` controller.  I actually am not sure how it worked before, but can't seem to get it to map correctly.

Is there something I'm missing?  Here is the relevant code:

Global.asax.cs:

```
...

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
...

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

TestAreaRegistration.cs:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I did move the Controllers folder up a level to be more in-line with how the project should be structured; beforehand it was in the Areas folder itself.  However, none of this worked before I moved that, so I doubt that is the case.  I also thought that Autofac had something to do with this, but I am less certain of that because if I shave the "Test" portion out of the URL it matches as expected.

I guess this all boils down to a question on how to check in a "generic" controllers directory first, before matching to an area-specific controller directory, even with an area specified in the URL.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**  If it helps, I noticed that in the existing MVC 2 solution, if I go to `Test/Home` for example, it will invoke the `Index` method of the `HomeController`.  However, this does not happen in the new solution.  Is this because there is no View associated with the new routes?  I have not made new .cshtml files for each of the corresponding .ascx files yet, but I didn't think that should matter much as they are used otherwise.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: It was a 404 error.

Comment: Yes,Its because of that u mention that you dont have make a View(.cshtml) file inside of the HomeController Index method.Make a view then try?

Comment: It ended up being related to the namespaces.  I'll post my code shortly as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the issue was related to namespaces.  I had seen that answer on questions like this, but those had to do with collisions finding views.  Here is the line I ended up adding to each of my Area registrations:

```
context.MapRoute(
        "Test_default",
        "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "Project.Web.Controllers", "Project.Web.Areas.Test.Controllers" }  //added this line
    );
```